# connectors to applications 'azureeventgrid' is not compatible with the Gmail

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

As part of microsoft integration service. I'm using an azure logic app that should send message to my GMAIL address each time an event is happening in a VM under a specified resource group.

Scenario applied is :

1. create RG + VM
2. create blank logic app
3. add event grid trigger
4. add condition ......
5. send email notificiations

(as of the link : [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app#:%7E:text=Sign%20in%20to%20the%20Azure,%27re%20done%2C%20select%20Create.)  )

But Logic app designer denied to save as I receive the following message :

```
Failed to save logic app XXXXla01. The operation on workflow 'XXXXla01' cannot be completed because it contains connectors to applications 'azureeventgrid' which are not compatible with the Gmail connector.
```

When workraround, I find this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-google-data-security-privacy-policy) that stated some google policies update.

I'm looking now for an alternative to this issue, where I can still use an azure resource that send notifications to my GMAIL address everytime an event is happening to my VM.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-google-data-security-privacy-policy#steps-for-affected-logic-apps

Comment: Thks @CSharpRocks for response. I succeed in delegating Gmail API authentication task but still face an issue as I run the logic app :

'Failed to start a run of logic app XXXXXla01. The template language expression evaluation failed: 'The execution of template trigger 'When_a_resource_event_occurs' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'splitOn' expression '@triggerBody()' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.'

Function expects table but finds NULL instead. There is no mention in MS documentation (article below).

Comment: Hi, as you have succeed in delegating gmail api authentication task, could you please provide the solution below. This can be beneficial to other communities. It will also help others understand your latest question post. Thanks.

Comment: You need to follow step by step the below process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with Gmail API was resolved with the procedure : [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-google-data-security-privacy-policy#steps-for-affected-logic-apps)