# Logic App to Monitor Azure VM not sending expected emails

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

As part of the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700269/connectors-to-applications-azureeventgrid-is-not-compatible-with-the-gmail?noredirect=1#comment110880063_62700269): when succeding in delegating Gmail API authentication task as of the new Google policies update, I still cope with this error message :

```
'Failed to start a run of logic app XXXXXla01. The template language expression evaluation failed: 'The execution of template trigger 'When_a_resource_event_occurs' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'splitOn' expression '@triggerBody()' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.'
```

Function " splitOn " expects table but finds NULL instead. There is no mention in MS documentation of the function expression.

Would anybody advise on this ?

Answer (score 0):

As the `When a resource event occurs` triggered when an Azure Event Grid **fires an event**, so you do not need set `Split On`.

[image]

The Logic App is same as you and here is the snapshot of result.

[image]

Comment: You can reopen a issue to detailed describe it with your logic app designer.

Comment: Hello Joey, please find my answer below

Answer (score 0):

my logic app designer looks like this :

[image]

I can run the logic app with no error message but still don't receive any message in my gmail box after for example resizing my azure VM in the RG.

Below is a logic app run example from run history, which refer to azure VM resize  :

[image]

at the ' If a virtual machine in your resource group has changed ' section you can remark expression result 'FALSE' which mean logic app is oriented to the 'If False' section that is empty.

I have followed step by step process, I don't know why I got to 'If False' section